# (R/SHINY) - Using selectInput to Choose (Which) Reactive Table to Display

Tags: r, shiny

So I have what in my head is a simple problem.

1. I have a selectInput. Let's call it report_select with the options "Report 1" and "Report 2" to choose from.
2. In addition, I have a textInput (which is used to specify an employee ID)
3. I have two reactives (lets call them r_one and r_two). These result in separate data based on the employee.
4. I have an output$table1

The goal: I want the dropdown to control WHICH of the two reactive reports to display in table1.

Note 1: The tables individually work fine. I can display one after the other without issue.
Note 2: I am using SHINY as well as tabsetpanel and tabpanel for organization

### Any methodology to help with this?

### METHOD 1: (Error is "Reading Objects from shionyoutput object not allowed)

```
library(shiny)
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# Globally Pull In Files
new_compdump_data <- read_xlsx("C:/temp/FILE.xlsx")

#Format Imported Data
clean_new <- subset(new_compdump_data,is.na(new_compdump_data$Term_Date))
clean_new$AIN <- as.numeric(clean_new$AIN)
clean_new$`MIP value` <- clean_new$`MIP%`*clean_new$Salary
# Begin UI
ui <- fluidPage(
titlePanel("Data Tool"),

sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
  selectInput(inputId = "report_select",
              label = "Select a Report",
              choices = c("Base Info","Stock Info")),
  textInput("stock_ain","AIN")
),  #End SideBarPanel             

mainPanel(
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel(title="Base Info",tableOutput("table1")
  )))
))

#======= SHINY - Server Section

server <- function(input, output) {

report1 <- reactive({
subset(clean_new[c(5,1,2,3)],clean_new$AIN==input$AIN)
})

report2 <- reactive({
subset(clean_new[c(5,6,7,8)],clean_new$AIN==input$AIN)
})

report_choose <- reactive({
ifelse(input$report_select=="Base Info",report1(),
ifelse(input$report_select=="Stock Info",report2()))
})

output$table1({
report_choose()
})

} #End server info

# Run the App
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

---

### METHOD 2: Error: Same as Above

Same as above but reactive for report_choose is:

```
report_choose <- reactive{(
switch(input$report_select,
"Base Info"=report1(),
"Stock Info"=report2())
)}
```

---

### METHOD 3: (Error is "Reading Objects from shionyoutput object not allowed)

Same (section) as above but

```
report_choose <- reactive({
if(input$report_select=="Base Info") {
report1()
} else {
report2()
}
})
```

Still no dice. Any ideas or methodology?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why  it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time  to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers,  and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!  See also: [ask]

Comment: Can you share the FILE.xlsx file? Sounds like a terribly simple fix, but having the file to verify the fix works before I post an answer always helps!

Comment: Hello OnlyPhantom! I appreciate the prompt response!  The example code i provided is a largely truncated version of the main program i have built.  In addition, the actual program uses many files.   In the example, the only things that the xlsx file needs is the AIN column (which is employee id) is in column 5 and the file has at least 8 columns. If you set up a file like that as a test i imagine you could copy/paste the above code.

Comment: Please provide the output of `dput(new_compdump_data)` so that we can have the dataset. Or `dput(head(new_compdump_data))` if it's enough.

Comment: Headers here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10I_KrymvfR05poz2b2PL1jeO6d0bc0wWGshBPaAx0Xk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Headers provided. Note that while in this example it would be posdible to display different columns in the same table, the idea im trying to tackle is displaying different reactives in on table output.